# Javascript or CSS to prevent scrolling inside element with overflown content

Tags: javascript, css

I have this website that's under development. Inside the body tag, i have two absolute positioned divs, side by side. One is 100% width of the window, the other 80%. They are wrapped by the body tag which is 100% width of the window.

To the body i have added "overflow-x:hidden" to hide the 80% width div and to prevent scrolling on horizontal. So far so good, except that on mobile devices you can touch drag (scroll) to the otherwise unscrollable content (second div). The same thing happens if you mouse wheel scroll right and left (press the middle mouse button and drag the mouse right and left). How could i prevent that scrolling from happening, without making the second element(the 80% width one) 0% width?

Comment: instead of doing hiding the overflow on the body, can you add `#mobileNav {display:none;}`?

Comment: Could be a workaround trough not displaying it. You gave me an idea that i shall try. Thank you. I am however opened to other suggestions as well, or a general answer on how to disable/nullify that behavior (pressed mouse wheel scroll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue (dare I say bug) with webkit browsers and the way they handle overflow on a single axis... You may have noticed that firefox isn't affected.

After a bit of experimenting it looks like it may be triggered by the combination of `overflow-x:hidden` with percentage based heights - see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OACDesigns/WFkSY/6/), the issue isn't present here initially but if you uncomment the `height:100%` css and run it again, you'll then notice the issue manifests:

http://jsfiddle.net/OACDesigns/WFkSY/6/

As others have mentioned, I think your best solution at this time is to make use of `display:none` on the navigation menu element as needed. 
The alternative would be to rethink how you've structured and styled the layout, and try to do it in such a way that doesn't trigger this bug.

Comment: Great answer, found the problem at least!

Comment: You don't have to add a height property to let the issue manifest. If you click with your mouse and keep it clicked and drag to the right you are able to scroll to the 80% sidenav which should actually be hidden since it is positioned in the overflow area. Seems like webkit is unable to handle overflow-x at all, no matter if it is safari, chrome or opera. :/