# the "pseudo element :after" part of an element is overriding overflow-x:hidden

Tags: css, overflow, pseudo-element

I have built a sample with two arrows. Basically the arrows are built with standard boxes - one with a `h2` one with a `p`

```
<header>
    <h2 class="maintitle">Test</h2>
    <p class="subtitle">Test about a test</p>
</header>
```

each box has two pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`. One creates a rectangle the other extends the box towards the page border to get a borderless arrow. The used css looks like that.

```
  html,
  body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
  }

  .wrap {
    width: 50em;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  section {
    margin-top:6em;
    width:100%;
    background-color: green;
    height:30em;
  }

  .maintitle,
  .subtitle {
    height: 3.5rem;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
    position:relative;
  }

  .maintitle {
    background-color: orange;
    padding-left:1rem;
    top: -1.77rem;
    text-align: left;
    &:before {
        content: "";
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        width: 999em;
        right:100%;
      background-color: orange;
    }
    &:after {
        content: "";
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        width:999em;
        left:100%;
    }
  }

  .subtitle {
    text-align: left;
    left:0;
    top:-1.77rem;
    padding-left: 3rem;
      background-color: grey;

    &:before {
        content: "";
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        width: 999em;
        right:100%;
    }
    &:after {
        content: "";
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        width: 999em;
        left:100%;
    background-color: grey;

    }

  }

  @media(min-width: 800px) {
    .maintitle {

        text-align: right;
        padding-right:1rem;
        &:after {

            right:-1.75rem;
            width:0;
            height:0;
            background:transparent;
            border-top: 1.8rem solid transparent;
            border-left: 1.8rem solid orange;
            border-bottom: 1.8rem solid transparent;

      }
    }
    .subtitle {
        top: 0;
        left:1.75rem;
        padding-left: 1rem;

      &:before {
            left:-1.75rem;
            width:0;
            height:0;
            background:transparent;
            border-top: 1.77rem solid transparent;
            border-right: 1.77rem solid grey;
            border-bottom: 1.77rem solid transparent;
        }

    }
  }
```

A pen showing an output is [here](http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/tvDjA)

Problem is the pseudo element of the grey arrow on the right is ignoring the `overflow-x:hidden` statement in e.g. safari (in chrome it works). if you click with the mouse and drag it to the right you get something like that:

[image: overflow-x gets ignored]

if i remove the pseudo element on the right and just enlarge the width of the grey box extensively it respects the `overflow-x:hidden` like shown in the following [pen](http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/jrBvA). Is there a way to get it work properly with the `.subtitle:after` version too?

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351797/javascript-or-css-to-prevent-scrolling-inside-element-with-overflown-content

Comment: yes and no. ;) Both issues have a buggy overflow-x, especially in webkit, as the root of the problem. Even in the jsfiddle example in your linked thread. In safari you can no matter if you have height: 100% commented out or not click and drag to the right and scroll to the basically hidden 80%part. Seems like it is not possible at all to cut and hide the overflow.